# Can I authorize n-users in the same device with nativescript-fingerprint-auth?

Tags: authentication, plugins, nativescript, fingerprint

I am designing a new application. Right now I am in a very early stage, deciding which technologies, frameworks, etc.. to use.
I think I will use nativescript with firebase. 
One of the App requirements is that multiple users can use the same device. With Firebase I know I can create multiple users and verify then through username & password.
To make the auth process leaner I would like to use the nativescript plugin nativescript-fingerprint-auth by Eddy Verbruggen.
then the question is very simple.

Can I use the same device for fingerprint auth multiple users?

Comment: That's simply not possible irrespective of what technology / framework you use. Android only lets you know whether the finger print was verified, it doesn't contain any user info.

Comment: Thanks @Manoj for your answer. Now then heading towards another solution.